# Using jQuery, how do I send a click event to a row of a dynamic table?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have an ajax form that returns a list and puts it into an HTML table.  I plan on using a click event in the Complete section of the ajax call but am unsure how to proceed.

What I need is a method that will be able to:

1. determine if there are any rows in the table, and
2. send a click event to that row.

I know how to do the click event, its the dynamic table that's causing me the pause.
Appreciate the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3281384/27457

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't not test it, but this should do the job :

```
alert( $('#myTable tr').length )
```

Put whatever the ID of your table is, class, or whatever and select all sub-elements `tr`. With the function length, she will return the number of `tr` inside your table. As you may know, each `tr` is a row.

So in final, your code will look like this :

```
if( $('#myTable tr').length > 0 ){
    // You have more then 1 row !
    $('#yourBtn').trigger('click');
}
```

---

If you want to click the first row, no matter what you can do this :

```
$('#myTable tr:first-child').trigger('click');
```

However, clicking a row isn't the best idea since a row ain't a link. If you want to click a link inside a `TD`, you can try this :

```
// Will find first TR (row)
// Will go to the TD with the index "1". I think it's the second TD because index start     at 0, but I am not sure anymore.
// Will find the first link, then trigger it as a "click".
$('#myTable tr:first-child').find('td:eq(1) a').trigger('click');
```

Didn't try the last one so I don't know if it work.

Comment: what if i want to click the first row regardless of its ID?  that's what i'm really interested in

Comment: @CarlosMendieta I know you said it worked but I updated my post. Maybe you'll find someone useful since I didn't really understood your first comment.

Comment: I completely appreciate the extra look.  I am fairly new to JQuery, though, from your initial post I was able to get what I needed to work PLUS understand how the syntax works.   Again, appreciate it.